# Fact and Dim tables in Database or Data Warehouse?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-warehouse, database-normalization

I am designing the schema for a database that takes in transactional user data, and the goal is to store the data, transform it, and display it back to the user in graphs on a dashboard.

My understanding is that we normalize the data to optimize storage in the Database and denormalize the data from the Database in the Data Warehouse into a format that can be used for data visualization/analysis.

Online, I have seen that Fact and Dim tables belong in the Data Warehouse, but I currently have them in my Database because of the nature of my data. Is my understanding wrong? I would think that the data warehouse joins the Fact and Dim tables in the Database and aggregates or performs other calculations for analysis?

I'm a newb with database design so any guidance would be massively appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to do some basic research. Typical distinction is between the `OLTP` (transactional processing) and `Data Warehouse` (business intelligence). *Both* of them need some *database* to store the data.

Comment: What is your (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? PS Your "understanding" is wrong, read about DB normalization including in & not in warehouse context. Follow a published information modeling & DB design method & ask re where you are 1st stuck/uncertain. PS "online" is not a good learning resource--unless you are reading one of dozens of published academic & industrial textbooks available there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing data in a "Data Warehouse" for later graphing is good.

Yes, "normalization" (into 'Dim' tables) is good, but it can be over-done.  Don't, for example, normalize DATEs or DATETIMEs; the downsides outweigh the benefits.

The typical "Fact" table needs very few indexes, possibly just a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Often, the data used in the Fact table needs to be summarized.  Then may happen even for graphing -- there is no use in plotting a million points.  You can boil it down to a thousand so that you don't choke the graphing software.

"Summary table(s)" should be built, then maintained incrementally (or continually).  Typically a summary table contains daily counts and subtotals for slices of the Fact table.  ("aggregation")  Then the "reports" or fetches for graphs work against the Summary table.  Such tables have index(es) that make the queries efficient, in addition to having many fewer rows than the Fact table.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse  (and 3 related articles).

For further discussion, let's see an attempt at `CREATE TABLE` for your Fact table and one of the graphs that you need.